# Which analytical function does this graph best correspond to?

Tags: curves

I have given the blue curve:

[image]

The datapoints are:

```
-2.00E+01   -6.70E+01
-1.70E+01   -6.10E+01
-1.40E+01   -5.50E+01
-1.10E+01   -4.89E+01
-8.00E+00   -4.30E+01
-5.00E+00   -3.71E+01
-2.00E+00   -3.13E+01
1.00E+00    -2.57E+01
4.00E+00    -2.04E+01
7.00E+00    -1.55E+01
1.00E+01    -1.10E+01
1.30E+01    -6.92E+00
1.60E+01    -3.09E+00
1.90E+01    5.40E-01
2.20E+01    4.02E+00
2.50E+01    7.38E+00
```

I would like to find an analytic, as simple as possible fit function $g(a_1,\cdots,a_N)$ where $a_n$ are arbitrary (not necessarily linear) parameters to fit to the values (in the range shown in the plot).

PS: If it matters: This is a logarithmic plot. The underlaying datapoints follow a power-law. If it would be a perfect power law, the curve would be linear. However, the curve bends for higher values of x and it is this bending that I would like to model.

Comment: Could you provide the data points ?

Comment: Added the datapoints

Comment: EDIT: I think the best answer is probably a simple Taylor series

Comment: Sorry but there’s not really a meaningful answer to a question like this. If you write down a random function there’s a good chance if you zoom in at the right place it will look like this. But that won’t give you any information about the system this data comes from.

Comment: I have added "in the range shown in the plot".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the data, it seems that a quadratic equation
$$y=a + b x+c x^2$$could be more than sufficient.

I obtained $R^2=0.999863$ and
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -27.5691   & 0.175178 & \{-27.9508,-27.1874\} \\
 b & 1.74388    & 0.009185& \{1.72387,1.7639\} \\
 c & -0.0134872 & 0.000692 & \{-0.014995,-0.011980\} \\
\end{array}$$

and the results are below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -20 & -67.0 & -67.84 \\
 -17 & -61.0 & -61.11 \\
 -14 & -55.0 & -54.63 \\
 -11 & -48.9 & -48.38 \\
 -8 &  -43.0 & -42.38 \\
 -5 &  -37.1 & -36.63 \\
 -2 &  -31.3 & -31.11 \\
 1 &   -25.7 & -25.84 \\
 4 &   -20.4 & -20.81 \\
 7 &   -15.5 & -16.02\\
 10 &  -11.0 & -11.48 \\
 13 &  -6.92 & -7.178 \\
 16 &  -3.09 & -3.120 \\
 19 &  +0.54 & +0.696 \\
 22 &  +4.02 & +4.268 \\
 25 &  +7.38 & +7.598
\end{array}
\right)$$ Adding a cubic term improves a little the results but the next coefficient is "almost non significant.

Use Excal trendlina for a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fit $y=a10^{\frac xb}$ you can take the log of both sides to get $\log y=\log a+\frac xb\log 10$.  This is a linear fit in the parameters $\log y, \log a, \frac 1b$.  Taking the log and the inverse of $b$ will change the weights of the errors and will change the fitted values a certain amount, but linear fits are easy and robust.  Alternately, you can avoid taking the logs and feed the fit to a nonlinear function minimizer.

Comment: May this is a misunderstanding but I **do not** want to fit $y = a 10^{x/b}$. I want to **know** which (simple, analytical) function the datapoints of the blue line best resemble. I use a nonlinear minimizer already (MATLAB) for fitting itself.

Comment: You can still fit $\log y$ vs $\log x$ using any fitter you want, then exponentiate the result.  The fact that it is so smooth should make fits work well.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. What is the function you suggest to use for fitting? Yes, I took the logarithm of $y$ already (and $x$ is already logarithmized, due to dB). If I fit versus any $y=a 10^{x/b}$ this fit is **linear** (logarithmically). I understand I can get different slopes and offsets for that linear function. But you can see the blue curve has a bend. I understand I can exponentiate it. But that still doesn't give me any shape that resembles the blue curve. If you would just provide an example, that would make things much easier.

Comment: I have also updated the question. Maybe it is less ambiguous now.